# How to boot a simple kernel with existing bootloaders

Tags: kernel, bootloader

I have written a simple kernel that is a simple binary file.
My question is: Is it possible to boot my kernel with LILO or Grub? How?

Comment: Have you read LILO or Grub documentation? Have you looked up online other toy kernels utilizing them?

Comment: Reading about multiboot specification might be a good place to start.

Comment: I have but they said that they can boot windows and nix kernels I dont know if it can boot a simple 16bit or 32bit kernel and they doesnt said anything about this

Comment: See how to boot `memtest`. For instance [Google memtest86+grub](https://www.google.ca/search?q=memtest86+grub).  The `memtest86` binary is identical to your simple kernel; basically expounding on what Alexey has said.